# Can I use a string to compare to an object key, and if it matches use the stored value, which is an operation

Tags: javascript, object, key

I'm currently working on a scientific calculator project, and figured instead of if else chaining I could create an object to store the functions as properties, to massively cut down on code and also not violate DRY heavily.

```
const calcFunctions = {
  ce: console.log("ce"),
  "x^2": square(),
  radic: Math.sqrt(expression),
  log: Math.log(expression),
  cos: Math.cos(expression),
  sin: Math.sin(expression),
  tan: Math.tan(expression),
  exp: Math.exp(expression),
  "=": console.log("="),
  undefined: console.log("undefined"),
};
```

What I am wondering is, is there a way to compare the statement (if this string is a key do this) and then extract the value from that statement and use it as an expression.

eg.

```
  value = "tan"
  If (calcfunctions.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
     expression = Math.tan(expression) // I want it to pull the value from the key:value of tan
  }
```

So far I have managed to get it to log a statement to the console IF it finds the key in the object, but beyond this I am lost.

```
  if (value !== undefined) {
    expression = "";
    ans.value = 0;
  }
  if (calcFunctions.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
    console.log(`${value} exists`);
  }
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

EDIT: FOR ADDITIONAL CONTEXT

The Value
is being gotten from an HTML element, when i click on the "calculator button" it's using an event listener and capturing the value

```
    const value = event.target.dataset["value"]
```

The Expression
This is the final number or sum that goes into the calculator input field, originally project used if else chaining, so we checked if value is === "x" expression = y

```
    else if (value == "cos") {
      expression = Math.cos(expression);
    }
```

Have tried using various suggestions found on stack overflow about using different methods however it mostly ends in undefined being returned. In the few cases it has not been undefined it has been a function does not exist error

I have also followed several tutorials but they are unfortunately not what i needed

Comment: `calcFunctions[value](expression)`

Comment: In `calcFunctions` what is the value of `expression`?

Comment: @RobinThomas what i was trying to do was have it as a variable argument, as it stands it's just a placeholder for whatever value is supposed to go into the math function

if (value == key in object) {
expression = Math.tan(x) // x being the number returned when i click a number button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all

```
const calcFunctions = {
  ce: console.log("ce"),
  "x^2": square(),
  radic: Math.sqrt(expression),
  log: Math.log(expression),
  cos: Math.cos(expression),
  sin: Math.sin(expression),
  tan: Math.tan(expression),
  exp: Math.exp(expression),
  "=": console.log("="),
  undefined: console.log("undefined"),
};
```

doesn't make too much sense, because you are not assigning functions to the properties, but results of function calls (which may even throw errors, depending on whether `expression` is defined somewhere or not). If you want your object to contain functions do it like this

```
const calcFunctions = {
  ce: () => console.log("ce"),
  "x^2": (x) => square(x),
  radic: (expression) => Math.sqrt(expression),
  log: (expression) => Math.log(expression),
  cos: (expression) => Math.cos(expression),
  sin: (expression) => Math.sin(expression),
  tan: (expression) => Math.tan(expression),
  exp: (expression) => Math.exp(expression),
  "=": () => console.log("="),
  undefined: () => console.log("undefined"),
};
```

Then you can do

```
let 
  whichFunction = "cos",
  func = calcFunctions[whichFunction],
  value = 13,
  result = undefined;

if (func) result = func(value);
```

or even simpler

```
let 
  whichFunction = "cos",
  value = 13;

let result = calcFunctions[whichFunction]?.(value);
```